# extract the names from an ordered the vector in R

Tags: r

Studying the http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Krijnen-IntroBioInfStatistics.pdf

Here's the question i have, how to extract the names from an ordered the vector. The problem in the book it asks to give the gene identifiers of the three genes(from the patients in disease stage B1) with the largest mean as an output.

The data set is from package "ALL"

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ALL")
```

Here's what i got so far,

```
library("ALL")
data("ALL")
B1 <- exprs(ALL[,ALL$BT=="B1"])
hist(B1)
mean(B1)
meanB1 <- apply(exprs(ALL[,ALL$BT=="B1"]),1,mean)
omeanB1 <- order((meanB1), decreasing=TRUE)
```

I'm wondering if there is a particular function i can call from R to extract just the names of the genes. In the package "golub" ,there is a golub.gnames to help extract the gene names.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein yes. i tried rownames(omeanB1) but gets NULL. What i want for the result is the names of the top 3 largest mean.

Comment: @abs27, use `names` (not `rownames`) for a list or vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're almost there. Once you have the order, you can apply it to `meanB1`:

```
head(meanB1[omeanB1])
# AFFX-hum_alu_at        31962_at      31957_r_at      40887_g_at      36546_r_at 
#        13.41648        13.16671        13.15995        13.10987        12.94578 
# 1288_s_at 
#  12.80290
```

To get the names of the top three genes, you can do:

```
names(meanB1[omeanB1])[1:3]
# [1] "AFFX-hum_alu_at" "31962_at"        "31957_r_at"
```

Comment: Thanks! I should check the R documentation though. head and names. gotcha!